# Unable to install CyanogenMod on Galaxy S2 i777

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom-flashing, rom-manager

I'm trying to use ROM Manager to install the [cm-10.1.3](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=i777&type=stable) ROM on my phone, but I'm getting the following error (from recovery.log):

```
-- Installing: /sdcard/bluetooth/cm-10.1.3-i777.zip
Finding update package...
I:Update location: /sdcard/bluetooth/cm-10.1.3-i777.zip
Opening update package...
Installing update...
Warning:  No file_contexts
script aborted: assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "i777" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "i777" || 
   getprop("ro.product.device") == "SGH-I777" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "SGH-I777" || 
   getprop("ro.product.device") == "SGH-S959G" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "SGH-S959G"
assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "i777" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "i777" || getprop("ro.product.device") == "SGH-I777" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "SGH-I777" || getprop("ro.product.device") == "SGH-S959G" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "SGH-S959G"
E:Error in /sdcard/bluetooth/cm-10.1.3-i777.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
result was NULL, message is: assert failed: install_zip("/sdcard/bluetooth/cm-10.1.3-i777.zip")
```

Here's info about my phone:

```
Model number:     SAMSUNG-SGH-I777
Android version:  4.1.2
Baseband version: I777UCMD8
Kernel version:   3.0.31-1154545-user
                  se.infra@SEP-126 #3
                  SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 23 22:10:17 KST 2013
Build number:     JZO54K.I777UCMD8
Recovery:         ClockworkMod 6.0.1.0
```

In addition, I found this set of instructions http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_i777, but using ROM Manager seems to be a much easier way to install the ROM. These instructions say to use the wipe data/factory reset option in CWM recovery - does this mean I should use the "Wipe Data and Cache" pre-installation option in ROM Manager?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [CyanogenMod Wiki](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Known_Issues_page_for_i777):

> "Status 7" Error
>   I have a stock AT&T Galaxy S2 (i777) which had been updated to the latest version of Android from AT&T. I followed the instructions for installing CM 10.1 but received the following error:
>
> ```
> assert failed: getprop("ro.product.device") == "i777" || 
> getprop("ro.build.product") == "i777" || 
> getprop("ro.product.device") == "SGH-I777" || 
> getprop("ro.build.product") == "SGH-I777" || 
> getprop("ro.product.device") == "SGH-S959G" ||
> getprop("ro.build.product") == "SGH-S959G"
> E:Error in /sdcard/cm-10.1.3-i777.zip (Status 7) Installation aborted.
> ```
>
> I tried updating to the very latest version of ClockworkMod Recovery, but that didn't help. The solution I found was to edit the "updater-script" file located at cm-10.1.3-i777.zip\META-INF\com\google\android. I removed the first line from that file which was performing the assert and getprop statements. I was certain I have an i777, so I was pretty sure that removing this line would be ok. After removing this line of code I pushed the CM zip file to my phone and was then able to install ok.
>
> This page was last modified on 3 December 2013, at 22:42.

So if you are 100% positive that you have an i777, then you can follow these steps:

- extract the update package zip file
- navigate to */META-INF/com/google/android
- open *updater-script* in a text editor like notepad++
- remove the first line that does the "assert" checks.
- zip the folder back up, using only "store", no compression.

Comment: Removing the first "assert" line was the correct solution, but unzipping and rezipping the folder didn't work. What did work was opening the archive in 7-Zip, right clicking on updater-script and choosing "edit", making the change, and saving the file.

Comment: unzipping them can be tricky. you have to keep the exact same folder structure, and compress it correctly. some tools do not handle that well. I am glad you got it to work with "edit" within the archive.

Answer (score 0):

To make it abundantly clear, since I had this exact same problem, you must unzip and zip the package back up using the same method used to create the zip file, which uses no compression(!).

In my case, I was on linux, and used ubuntu's Archive Manager application to view the contents of the archive. I then found the file causing the issue in /META-INF/com/google/android called 'updater-script' and removed the first line. The archive manager application then handled re-assembly of the archive after I saved the file. Then flashing the rom worked.